# How to design/make an anchor tag look the exact same like a button (very vague, but looks at the details below)

Tags: html, css

This is a normal button tag on Edge, whatever css edge applies to button tags by default, no modifications from me whatsoever. https://prnt.sc/18mosg9

This is my attempt to create something similar: https://prnt.sc/18moxm4
or really, just an anchor that looks/resembles a button.

I think the issue is fairly clear, but to word it out, how do I make it so that the anchor tag is a full rectangle rather than a dynamically adjusting "thing" based on the text inside the anchor tag? Both the button and anchor tags contains the exact same text, which includes a `<br>` tag inside it.

I'm not entirely sure about how to do this, nor do I have an idea on how or if it's even possible.

Current CSS for the anchor is

```
.anchorBTN {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: I suggest starting by learning more about CSS `display` property. You can also use browser developer tools (Ctrl+F12 or Cmd+F12) to inspect default styles applied to `button` and use those to build your own custom styles, noting that styles can vary by browser.

Comment: @Spectric it's probably just poor wording on my part, but it basically just slices off part of the anchor tag when it reaches the `<br>` tag, then throws in on the next line down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> slices off part of the anchor tag when it reaches the `<br>` tag

This can be fixed by applying `display:block` to the anchor:

```css
.anchorBTN {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<b>With display:block:</b><br/>
<a class="anchorBTN">PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER<br/>PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER</a>

<hr>

<b>Without display:block</b><br/>
<a class="anchorBTN" style="display:unset">PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER<br/>PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER</a>
```

Comment: nvm, that makes a lot of sense, when I first tried display block I believe I had set a width and height on it, so it looked very weird which led me to delete display block without removing the width and height first, which was why I never went and tried it again